# Postgres: check array of text has elements castable to domain type in the where clause of a select statement

Tags: postgresql

Given I have defined domains with check constraints and I have the following query:

```
SELECT pm.name, ps.name, pm.id, ps.id 
FROM 
    pylon_modules pm
    INNER JOIN 
    pylon_symbols ps ON pm.id = ps.module_id
WHERE pm.name  in ('Test','test') and ps.name in ('bang');
```

What is the simplest way to cast the symbols used in the where clause ? I need to assert they match a domain type.

Above 'Test' is not a valid module name.

I can set up a stored procedure but the query is so simple I'd prefer to prepare it.

If I use a stored procedure do I have to create an array version of my domain types ?

There is [this](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/228-PostgreSQL-Array-The-ANY-and-Contains-trick.html), but it requires the cast target is of array type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does the trick, your domains constraint violations will trigger errors:

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION resolve_symbols(modules TEXT[], symbols TEXT[])
RETURNS TABLE(
  moduleName VARCHAR(16),
  symbolName VARCHAR(16),
  moduleId INT,
  symbolId INT
) AS $body$
  SELECT pm.name, ps.name, pm.id , ps.id
  FROM pylon_modules pm
    INNER JOIN pylon_symbols ps ON pm.id = ps.module_id
  WHERE pm.name  IN (SELECT unnest(modules)::public.module_name) AND 
        ps.name  IN (SELECT unnest(symbols)::public.element_name)
$body$ LANGUAGE sql;`